# MongoDB flatten result list of certains fields in list of dicts

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Lest say I have data like

```
[{
  _id: 1, 
  items: [
    {a: 1, b: 2},
    {a: 2, b: 2},
    {a: 15, b: 7}
  ]
}, {
  _id: 2, 
  items: [
    {a: 15, b: 9},
    {a: 15, b: 9},
    {a: 41, b: 9}
  ]
}]
```

I want to ask for items.a elements, so i result I will have

```
[[
  1,
  2,
  15
], [
  15,
  15,
  41
]]
```

I know that

```
db.collection.find({}, {"items.a": true, "_id": false})
```

will return

```
[{
  items: [
    {a: 1},
    {a: 2},
    {a: 15}
  ]
}, {
  items: [
    {a: 15},
    {a: 15},
    {a: 41}
  ]
}]
```

And that is not what I am looking for.

And is it worth to calculate it in MongoDB or I can calculate it in Python?

Edit:
And what if I want to check it by for example: return every list that contains items.a: 1

so the result should be in that case

```
[[
  1,
  2,
  15
]]
```

Comment: You can try `db.collection.distinct("items.a",{"items.a":1})`;

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following aggregation pipeline which uses the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator within a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline to create the arrays of values for mapped elements of the embedded document `a` field:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "elements": {
                "$push": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$items",
                        "as": "item",
                        "in": "$$item.a"
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
])
```

**Sample Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "elements" : [ 
        [ 
            1, 
            2, 
            15
        ], 
        [ 
            15, 
            15, 
            41
        ]
    ]
}
```

---

If you you only want to return all items where the one of the elements has a value of 1, you would need to place a **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** filter before the grouping, as in the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "items.a": 1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "elements": {
                "$push": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$items",
                        "as": "item",
                        "in": "$$item.a"
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "elements" : [ 
        [ 
            1, 
            2, 
            15
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: And what if I want to find by items.a = 1, so result will be {"_id" : null, "elements" : [[1,  2,  15]]}?

Comment: You would need to include a `$match` filter first, as in the update above.